# Turning a cup into a donut: parametrising the continuous deformation

Tags: general-topology, computer-science

A cup and a donut are topologically equivalent because one can be continuously deformed into another. What if you had a particular cup and a particular donut and wanted to write down (or simulate on a computer) this deformation explicitly?

Is there a natural class of continuous deformations that can serve as candidates? Are there any algorithms for finding such deformations (approximately or exactly)?

Comment: Offhand it seems to me that if you could find a single continuous bijective mapping between $C$ and $D$, you could construct the deformation by a simple linear interpolation between that mapping and the identity mapping. That is, if $B:C\to D$ is the bijection, then the deformation is $H_t : c\mapsto c(1-t)+B(c)t$ for $t\in[0,1]$. This simple linear mapping won't work for any two equivalent manifolds, but it should work for $C$ and $D$.

Comment: Define "donut". Should the cup itself be a cored out cylinder, and the handle a cored out half-cylinder?

Comment: The donut is the easy part, because a torus has a particularly simple parametrization. Parameterizing the cup is trickier. This is why I only gave my suggestion in terms of an already-existing bijection $B$ between the two surfaces. Without knowing specifically how the surfaces themselves are represented, it seems impossible to be more specific about the deformation.

Comment: I don't really care about the cup and donut, it's just an example. Really I'm interested in computationally finding deformations that approximately deform one high dimensional manifold into another. Intuitively it's clear that you want to "stretch" and "bend" the manifold to get the right shape. But is there a concrete family of stretches and bends that may be used to construct the wanted deformation?

Comment: @David Unless you're more specific about what kinds of manifolds you're interested in, I don't think it's possible to answer the question.

Comment: I am not sure if there's a "class of continuous deformations", but I found some Python codes that might shed some inspiration for you, for they show a specific parametrization for a mug, and for a torus, and the way to go continuously from one to the other in here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262094/how-can-i-transform-my-coffee-cup-into-a-torus-as-seen-on-wikipidea